# Splitting class responsibilities without exposing too much

Tags: c++, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I'm having a hard time finding good ways to split class responsibilities without having to expose too much of the original class.

As a ***simple*** example I've got this `Product` class which provides all the operations a product can do, but can also draw itself onto the GUI:

```
/* Only relevant pieces shown. */
class Product
{
public:

    void
    Draw(QPainter& painter);

private:

    QPointF mPosition;
    Rotation mRotation;
    QColor mFillColor;
    QColor mOutlineColor;
};
```

I feel this breaks the SRP. The way a `Product` is to be drawn can change and this has nothing to do with the management of a `Product`. Or perhaps, later, there might be demand for multiple ways to draw a `Product` and one wouldn't want to keep modifying the `Product` class itself for this.

But, off course, as soon as one wants to move the drawing code elsewhere, those private variables will have to be exposed, which also does not sit right with me. I'd be adding a bunch of getters (which feels damn ugly in and off itself) and I'd be tying myself down to maintaining this new "interface" forever. It also collides with the "Tell, don't ask" principle.

Surely there have to be better methods for problems like these ?
(examples with C++ code would be nice, in stead of just theorizing).

Comment: Just like the `Draw` function might not belong in the `Product` class, so is it with the `Draw` specific member variables. When you move `Draw` out of the `Product` class, does it really make sense to keep its drawing position or color inside the `Product` class?

Comment: what actually is a`Product` ? Naively I would expect it to model something like the result of some `a * b`. Why does it have a position, rotation fill and outline color? Btw those members look like the single responsibility of the class is to have something that can be drawn, otherwise why does it have members for fill and outline color?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @idclev463035818 A `Product` as in a product our company produces, not the result of multiplication. Some members have multiple uses. For example the position information is used for product management (stuff like collision detection when moving) AND for drawing off course. And where else would you keep information about the color of each product then with the product itself ?

Comment: "Collision detection"? That makes no sense for a physical product, only as part of computer simulation or *drawing*. Or do you mean things like shelf-space? Then that would probably be better of using a better abstraction. If you draw a product on a shelf, then get the shelf-position and calculate drawing position instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's a computer simulation. The products are drawn on a conveyor so the user can manipulate them in order to calculate robot positions for palletizing. Does that make much of a diffirence ? It still feels like a product should not know how to draw itself - what if I want to draw in 3D tomorrow in stead of 2D? The object that keeps track of the product should have nothing to do with that.

Comment: In that case it actually makes more sense to keep the drawing inside the `Product` class itself, I think.